# Using Celery with a cookiecutter-django project

Tags: django, docker-compose, celery, cookiecutter-django

I'm currently building a small django project and I decided to use cookiecutter-django for a base as everything I need was included. When setting up the project I asked cookiecutter-django to include the settings for Celery and I can find everything in the project, so far so good. However I do have some issues with getting Celery to run as it should. When I start a task from from an app nothing happens.

The docker containers are all started properly. Django and Postgres work, Redis is up and I was able to bash into the container and query it. From the console output I see that the celeryworker container is up and running.  I also see that my tasks are being recognized by Celery:

```
celeryworker_1  | [tasks]
celeryworker_1  |   . metagrabber.taskapp.celery.debug_task
celeryworker_1  |   . scan_and_extract_meta
celeryworker_1  |   . start_job
```

After puzzling a lot about this I decided to create a new Docker container for Flower to see what's happening under the hood. Interestingly enough I can see that there is a worker and its name is correct (I compared the worker ID in the Celery container). However if I start a task from one of my views like this:

```
celery_task_id = start_job_task.delay(job.id)
```

I don't see any tasks coming in on Flower. I can see that `celery_task_id` gets a UUID, but that's everything. Nothing to see on Flower (all counts for active, processed, failed, succeeded, retried remain on 0). If I execute bash in my Redis container and use `redis-cli` I don't see a queue called `celery`, which just means that there is no Celery task. There might (I say *might*) be a clue left by Flower on the logs:

```
flower_1        | [W 180304 10:31:05 control:44] 'stats' inspect method failed
flower_1        | [W 180304 10:31:05 control:44] 'active_queues' inspect method failed
flower_1        | [W 180304 10:31:05 control:44] 'registered' inspect method failed
flower_1        | [W 180304 10:31:05 control:44] 'scheduled' inspect method failed
```

But to be honest I don't know how this could help me.

So I went ahead and added some logging to see what's going on and I found out that actually my Django container tries to do the work when I execute `start_job_task.delay(job.id)` instead of handing over to Celery. I somehow have the feeling that all this has some bad connection to Redis. But how? The configuration in the docker-compose file just looks fine the way that cookiecutter set things up:

```
  redis:
    image: redis:3.0

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    environment:
      - C_FORCE_ROOT=true # just for local testing
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker.sh
```

I also tried exposing the port on the Redis container manually, but that didn't get me any further.

For completeness, here are my Celery settings from my config files. As set up with cookiecutter:

```
# base.py
INSTALLED_APPS += ['mailspidy.taskapp.celery.CeleryConfig']
CELERY_BROKER_URL = env('CELERY_BROKER_URL', default='django://')
if CELERY_BROKER_URL == 'django://':
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://'
else:
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = CELERY_BROKER_URL

# local.py
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```

Any ideas why the tasks don't get sent to Celery?

Comment: I found out that my Django container tries to do the work when I execute `start_job_task.delay(job.id)` instead of handing over to Celery.-  Is `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` set to `True`

Comment: Also can you share start-celeryworker.sh and celery settings

Comment: @NihalSharma I updated my post to include my Celery settings. As you can see: always eager is set to true. I also know that the broker url points to `redis://redis:6379/0` and my redis container says it's listening to Port 6379, so that seems to be in order..

Comment: if `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER` is true, celery will not do anything. The task will not run in async mode, which is the case with you. Set it to `False` and check.

Comment: Refer - http://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/django-celery/en/2.4/cookbook/unit-testing.html

Comment: That was the issue. I guess I had issues when setting it to false previously as I had a bug in the celery task and without logging I didn't see an issue on the output.. Thanks for the help!